# MySQL ODBC on Mac OS X 10.8

Tags: mysql, macos, odbc, osx-mountain-lion

I've found some problems while trying to connect to a remote MySQL database using MySQL's ODBC connector.
I'm on Mac OS X 10.8.2 and I've installed MySQL ODBC connector 5.2.4. Every time I tried to connect using this ODBC my connection gets refused.

Does anyone have the same issue? Is there any workaround?

**Edit:** I tested the ODBC connection with iODBC and I got the following result:

```
SQLDriverConnect = [iODBC][Driver Manager]dlopen(/usr/local/lib/libmyodbc5.so, 6): image not found (0) SQLSTATE=00000
SQLDriverConnect = [iODBC][Driver Manager]Specified driver could not be loaded (0) SQLSTATE=IM003
```

Answer (score 1):

The [MySQL Connector/ODBC 2.5.6 for Mac OS X](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/) comes only in versions for 10.6 (Snow Leopard) and 10.7 (Lion). I don't know about any official support from MySQL for Mac OS X versions 10.8 (Mountain Lion) or even 10.9 (Mavericks)!

Paid licensed solutions put more effort on supporting the latest Mac OS X versions... I have tried myself the evaluation version [Actual ODBC Pack for Mac OS X](http://www.actualtech.com/download.php) with Mavericks and could get 3 rows per recordset. You can try that and if it works see if it's worth paying for unlimited rows.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the ODBC Administrator utility or the command line?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-odbc-configuration-dsn-macosx.html

**Edit:** I don't think I noticed "remote" server. Does that remote server had a user with permissions to connect from your IP address?

Comment: Hi! First of all, thanks for your answer. I tried both ways but the result was the same.... I'm a little stuck with this ...

Comment: Hi! Yes I have the proper permissions. In fact, I download a free trial of the this ODBC: http://www.actualtech.com and it worked fine. But I need to find a way to connect to my database using MySQL's ODBC connector... :(

Comment: do you know if there is any MySQL tool for testing the ODBC connection?

Answer (score 0):

@Jason Sundram (OP): Just FYI, Oracle has (in response to my filing bug reports about their documentation) updated the Mac OS X, mysql 5 installation instructions for Connector/ODBC, at:
 https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-installation-binary-osx.html

Following those steps might be helpful. They worked for me in OS X 10.9 (Mavericks).  But, I'm also not trying to do precisely what you are, with your environment, so I'm not sure what effect reinstalling as instructed there may have on your problem.